# How to build a new dataframe from rows of original dataframe in a loop in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, for-loop

I have a dataframe df1 filled with certain data and empty dataframe df2.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5], 'b':[6,7,8,9,0]}, columns=['a','b'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([])
```

I loop over df1 with iterrows and want to fill df2 with some rows of df1. I try this, but am getting empty dataframe df2:

```
for idx, row in df1.iterrows():
    df2.append(pd.DataFrame(row, index=[0]), ignore_index=True)
```

I know I can make it easy for simple append, but my target case has a complex condition that is why I am using the loop. 
Please, help me to make it right. BR

Answer (score 0):

Sorry! Silly mistake - thought the assignment is done automatically, but this is not true. This is what I was looking for: `df2 = df2.append(row, ignore_index=True)`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to fill df2 with rows from df1 according to a condition.

For example if you want all the rows where column a is > 2, you can write :

```
df2 = df1[df1['a']>2]
```

You do not need a loop, loops are too expensive in time and memory. Use the pandas optimized functionalities instead.